# Summing reciprocal logs of different bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms, factorial, fractions

I recently took a math test that had the following problem:
$$
\frac{1}{\log_{2}50!} + \frac{1}{\log_{3}50!} + \frac{1}{\log_{4}50!} + \dots + \frac{1}{\log_{50}50!}
$$
The sum is equal to 1. I understand that the logs can be broken down into (first fraction shown)
$$
\frac{1}{\log_{2}1 + \log_{2}2 + \log_{2}3 + \dots + \log_{2}50}
$$

How do the fractions with such irrational values become $1$? Is there a formula or does one simply need to combine fractions and use the basic properties of logs?

Comment: In this case you will see that the properties of log will give you your answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{\log_{2}50!} + \frac{1}{\log_{3}50!} + \frac{1}{\log_{4}50!} + \dots + \frac{1}{\log_{50}50!}
$$
$$=\log_{50!}2+\log_{50!}3+\log_{50!}4+...+\log_{50!}50$$
$$=\log_{50!}(2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot...50)$$
$$=\log_{50!}(50!)$$
$$=1$$

Comment: This uses a rule I'd never heard of! http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.htm#base switch

Comment: @Dancrumb Which rule are you talking of?

Comment: The one I linked to

Comment: In case the link doesn't work: The logarithm base switch rule.

Comment: Presumably $\log_a( b) = 1/ \log_b( a)$ which can be shown from $b^{\log_b(a) \log_a(b)} = \left(b^{\log_b(a)}\right)^{\log_a(b)} =  a^{log_a(b)} = b$ so $\log_b(a) \log_a(b) = 1$

Answer (score 12):

HINT: use that $\log_2 50!=\frac{\ln(50!)}{\ln(2)}$ thus we get
$$\frac{\ln(2)+\ln(3)+...+\ln(49)+\ln(50)}{\ln(50!)}=\frac{\ln(50!)}{\ln(50!)}=1$$

Comment: Not complaining, but why did you call it a hint, when you gave the entire solution?

Answer (score 9):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{50}\frac{1}{\log_k(50!)}=\sum_{k=2}^{50}\frac{1}{\frac{\log(50!)}{\log k}}=\sum_{k=2}^{50}\frac{\log k}{\log(50!)}=\frac{1}{\log(50!)}\sum_{k=2}^{50}\log k=\frac{\log(50!)}{\log(50!)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

This is a general result.  We can write for any $N$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{\sum_{m=2}^N \log_n(m)}&=\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{\sum_{m=2}^N \frac{\log_b (m)}{\log_b(n)}}\\\\
&=\frac{\sum_{n=2}^N\log_b(n)}{\sum_{m=2}^N\log_b(m)}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

where we used $\log_n(m)=\frac{\log_b(n)}{\log_b(m)}$.  And we are done!